# Problems with passing a hashmap from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android

Im having problems I've followed a few examples but none of them seems to work.
I'm trying to send the HashMap to a fragment so that i can retrieve the values and place them onto text-views.

I'm calling the method(SendInfoToFragment) to pass the hashmap to the fragment inside the method(splitStringBuilder) where we split the JSONObject. I try to retrieve it the bundle i send on the OnAttachmethod inside the fragment. However i keep getting "java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

This is my main Activity.

```
public class WeatherActivity extends MenuActivity {

    public JSONObject splitStringBuilder(String builder) throws JSONException {
        String Info = (builder);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Info);
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(Info);
        JSONArray weatherObj = obj.getJSONArray("consolidated_weather");
        System.out.println(obj.get("title"));

        for(int x = 0; x < 6; x ++ )
        {
            WeatherForeCast weatherObject = new WeatherForeCast();
            obj = weatherObj.getJSONObject(x);

            int temperature = obj.getInt("the_temp");
            int wind_speed = obj.getInt("wind_speed");
            int air_pressure = obj.getInt("air_pressure");
            int humidity = obj.getInt("humidity");
            String weather_state = obj.getString("weather_state_name");
            String date = obj.getString("applicable_date");

            weatherObject.setTemperature(temperature);
            weatherObject.setWindSpeed(wind_speed);
            weatherObject.setAirPressure(air_pressure);
            weatherObject.setHumidity(humidity);
            weatherObject.setWeatherState(weather_state);
            weatherObject.setDate(date);
            String counter = String.valueOf(x);
            HashMapWeatherInformation.put(counter,weatherObject);

        }
        SendInfoToFragment(HashMapWeatherInformation);
        return obj2;
    }


    private class WeatherAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void , Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                weatherInfo = callApi();
                jsWeatherInfo = splitStringBuilder(weatherInfo);

            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


        }
    }
    public void SendInfoToFragment(HashMap hashMap) {
        FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DisplayWeatherFrag weatherFrag = new DisplayWeatherFrag();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("hashmap", hashMap);
        weatherFrag.setArguments(bundle);
                fm.add(R.id.fragment ,weatherFrag);
                        fm.commit();

    }
    public void runtheDamnThing(String string) {
        WeatherAsyncTask weatherAsyncTask = new WeatherAsyncTask();
        weatherAsyncTask.execute(string);
    }




    }
```

This is my fragment

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DisplayWeatherFrag extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_weather, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        HashMap<String, WeatherForeCast>HashMapWeatherInfo = null;
        Bundle b;
        b = getArguments();
        HashMapWeatherInfo = (HashMap<String, WeatherForeCast>) b.getSerializable("hashmap");

    }

}
```

This is the error code that i'm getting

```
2019-03-19 17:32:31.762 17365-17365/com.fan4.outdoorplus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fan4.outdoorplus, PID: 17365
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.fan4.outdoorplus.WeatherFragments.DisplayWeatherFrag.onActivityCreated(DisplayWeatherFrag.java:68)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1483)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-03-19 17:32:31.849 1932-2013/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '9ab1457 PopupWindow:1c45845 (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-03-19 17:32:31.850 1932-2013/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '8221b13 com.fan4.outdoorplus/com.fan4.outdoorplus.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-03-19 17:32:32.061 2592-2866/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-03-19 17:32:32.061 2592-2866/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it would be to have the Hashmap(or any other object) inside the activity with a getter. Then you can get it directly from there.

In Fragment just do:

```
hashmap = ((WeatherActivity) getActivity()).getMyHashMap()
```

And make sure you have the `getMyHashMap()` method in your WeatherActivity.